# how to group and filter on aggregate in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, group-by, filtering, aggregate, ssrs-2012

I have a requirement to report the number of people who have more than one record in the dataset for my SSRS report and I can't quite get how to filter on the grouping.

So if the dataset results are:

```
ID     PersonID    FileID
1      1234         abc
2      7890         ade
3      5647         aer
4      1234         xyz
```

I would like to report 1.  There is one person who has more than 1 record.

Is there an expression or something I can use to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have to filter you report only persons with more than one record? or do you need to calculate the number of persons with more than one record?

Comment: I need to include as a calculation on the report the number of persons with more than 1 record.

Comment: What result you want to show in your report?

Comment: I have to show all the details and a calculated field that shows how many people are there more than once.

Comment: You can't filter an aggregate on a **table** but you can filter a **group** by an aggregate. I think it would be better to **Group By** your `Person ID` and **Filter** the Group for a `COUNT > 1`.  If you need to show all then don't filter and use COUNT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LookupSet and CountDistinct function to get the required count, however you will need the textbox used to show the calculation be in a scope.

If you want to show the number of persons with more than one record as a total in your table use this expression:

```
=CountDistinct(
IIF(
  LookupSet(
    Fields!PersonID.Value,Fields!PersonID.Value,
    Fields!ID.Value,"DataSetName"
  ).Length>1,Fields!PersonID.Value,Nothing)
)
```

Set it outside any group scope:

[image]

However if you want to show the number of persons with more than one record outside your tablix in a textbox, you can add an additional tablix and delete the necessary rows and columns to leave only one textbox then set the dataset property to the dataset name you are using and use the same expression.

[image]

It should produce:

[image]

Note my dataset has more rows to ilustrate the functionality. In the right side there is only one textbox with the count.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!  I used the single cell tablix and it is working great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result to be something like shown below.

**Steps:**

1. Create a group on Person ID
2. `Right Click on Group > Add Total > Before`
3. Add a column and put `=Count(Fields!PersonID.Value)`
4. If you want to display only Persons having more than one, set the visibility property of the tablix row.

[image]

Comment: No I want the results to be a single box that says "1"

Comment: Can't you handle it on Dataset Query level to return 1? What query (SQL) you are using in your dataset?